# How to get the transaction id of paypal(1.4.3)in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, paypal

I am using the paypal 1.4.3 version.

Total paypal is working fine and the responce is coming as

```
{
client =     {
 environment = sandbox;
 "paypal_sdk_version" = "1.4.3";
  platform = iOS;
 "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
};
payment =     {
 amount = "190.50";
"currency_code" = USD;
"short_description" = Vegetables;
};
"proof_of_payment" =     {
  "adaptive_payment" =         {
            "app_id" = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
            "pay_key" = "AP-0W362760MW159460W";
            "payment_exec_status" = COMPLETED;
             timestamp = "2013-07-25T04:12:46.646-07:00";
           };
   };
}
```

But i want the transation id also.How i can get the transaction id in this version of paypal in ios

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get the [latest release](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases) which is currently 1.4.2.

Then, read about [verifying a payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) which details steps to get transaction details.